# Density plot for multiple group shows one line, however legend shows 3

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, density-plot

I am analyzing US election data volume from Google trend. I type the below command in R studio.

The `poliData` dataframe contains the `SearchVolume` for all months for three `Politician`s.

```
ggplot(data = poliData, aes(x=Date, group=Politician, colour=Politician)) +
    geom_density()
```

[image]

But I only get the density line (blue) for one politician only with the above command.See the attached picture. Can you please help

Comment: Would you be able to use ```dput()``` to share the actual data?

Comment: I cant put the whole data set due to character limit in comments

Comment: Date      Politician SearchVolume
1   2004-01-01    Donald Trump            2
2   2004-02-01    Donald Trump            2
3   2004-03-01    Donald Trump            2
4   2004-04-01    Donald Trump            4
5   2004-05-01    Donald Trump            1
6   2004-06-01    Donald Trump            1
7   2004-07-01    Donald Trump            1  ...............This is how my dataset looks and there are more rows for other politician type..

Comment: It is possible that all plots are overlapping. Please try the following to see if you get 3 identical density functions: 

ggplot(data = poliData, aes(x=Date, group=Politician, colour=Politician)) +
    geom_density() + facet_wrap(~Politician,scales = 'free')

Comment: HI Seshadri, you are correct the graphs were overlapping. Thank you , its the same line of curve in all three political values which I see in the individual facet graph. I need to dig into my data now. Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks sheshari , it did on top of each other thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got three lines on top each other because `Date` variable values are the same for all three `politician`s. My understanding of your analysis could be something like this:

```
ggplot(data = poliData, 
       aes(x=Date, colour=Politician, 
           weight = SearchVolume/sum(SearchVolume))) +
  geom_density()
```

Adding `weight` should produce distinct lines for different politicians. If this is not what you wanted, please `dput` your data for others to work out a solution for you. Also, as I do not have the data, I have not tested the above code yet. Please let me know if it does not work.

Comment: Hi Zhiqiang, you are absolutely right. I can now see three distinct line. So my problem is solved for now, thank you so much. However,I'm not fully sure how R handles this as for each week, the volume is different for three politicians and I'm assuming the density is calculated based on this search volume. I'll sit with my peer to reverse engineer it. But thanks again. Really appreciate your help. Regards Neha